# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied passing variable but works when hard-coded

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm trying to get watchdog setup to feed new files into the dcmread function but can't seem to get past a PermissionError.

```
        print("Watchdog received created event - % s." % event.src_path)
        home = r'C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\TEST_DCM_DIR'
        fn = os.path.basename(event.src_path)
        print(fn)
        dcmpath = glob.glob(home + '\\' + fn)
        print(dcmpath[0])
        dcmpath2 = r'C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\TEST_DCM_DIR\test.dcm'
        print(dcmpath2)
        ds = dcmread(dcmpath[0])
```

Both the hard coded and the variable paths print the same file path, but when I use the variable I get the following errors.

```
File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 861, in dcmread
fp = open(fp, 'rb')

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\name\\PycharmProjects\\TEST_DCM_DIR\\test.dcm'
```

The code works fine when I pass through the hard-coded path which makes me think it isn't a permission thing (from searching stackoverflow). I'm hoping it's something to do with how I'm compiling the path. I've tried os.path.join methods (dcmpath = os.path.join(home, fn)) and using the event.src_path handle too and haven't managed to crack it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm running this code on a Windows machine.

edit: What appeared to be the problem was that the file was being read before it was released from copying. Adding a time.sleep(2) line before passing the path to dcmread solved this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `glob.glob()`? There's no wildcards.

Comment: The error isn't saying that the file doesn't exist. It says it exists but you don't have permission to read it. So you're creating the path correctly. Something else is changing the permissions in the two cases.

Comment: To be honest I'm only using glob.glob because I found it in another example when I was trying to troubleshoot why dcmpath = os.path.join(home, fn) wasn't working

Comment: Why are you using basename in the first place? Isn't `event.src_path` the full path of the file?

Comment: Yes - i tried that too and got the same error. I tried using event.src_path, os.path.join, and glob.glob. All gave me the same error.

Comment: What do you see if you check the permissions on the file? Is the file owner running the script?

Comment: Do you just mean if I go to the security settings of the file? I am allowed (as is system) to do everything except 'special permissions'

Comment: There must be something else different when you run the script with the variable or hard-coded. That can't change the file permissions by itself.

Comment: The only thing I change is the ds = dcmread() line.

Comment: Okay - this got me think actually that maybe the fact watchdog was responding before the file was released from being copied. I added a time.sleep before reading the dcm and this solved my problem! This is a little embarrassing but thanks for pointing me in that direction

Comment: @browser answer worked perfectly fine. Just added time.sleep(1) before pydicom.dcmread(). Works like a charm.